# can't fetch object from nsdictionary...?

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

I've done this thing lots and lots of time. But I don't know why I can't figure out what is the issue with this object when I try to fetch it from NSDictionary.

I've NSMutableArray object which have below data.

> (
>           {
>           SelectUserDataResult = "[{
>       'UserID': '3D5CC4E6-25E8-4591-A84A-6BD7D020DB17',
>       'ClientID': '895D7BE5-B5D0-48AE-8AAB-6863FCD1D5BF',
>       'TimeZoneCulture_Term': 'en-US',
>       'Currency_Term': 'GBP',
>       'LoginLogID': 'c76960b1-aa24-454f-9fe7-f4f3960fefd4'
>   }]";
>       }
>   )

Now I fetch my first object like

```
NSDictionary *dicResponse = [[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)[data objectAtIndex:0]] objectForKey:@"SelectUserDataResult"];
NSLog(@"%@",dicResponse);
```

> [{
>       'UserID': '3D5CC4E6-25E8-4591-A84A-6BD7D020DB17',
>       'ClientID': '895D7BE5-B5D0-48AE-8AAB-6863FCD1D5BF',
>       'TimeZoneCulture_Term': 'en-US',
>       'Currency_Term': 'GBP',
>       'LoginLogID': 'c76960b1-aa24-454f-9fe7-f4f3960fefd4'
>   }]

Now, from above I want fetch **UserID** and other things so, I just code like

```
NSString *abc = [dicResponse objectForKey:@"UserID"];
```

but it gives me error like

> -[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a70200

Can't find where I'm wrong.

Thanks

=========
Part-2

I just mange to change my NSMutableArray object data as below

> (
>   "[{
>       'UserID': '3D5CC4E6-25E8-4591-A84A-6BD7D020DB17',
>       'ClientID': '895D7BE5-B5D0-48AE-8AAB-6863FCD1D5BF',
>       'TimeZoneCulture_Term': 'en-US',
>       'Currency_Term': 'GBP',
>       'LoginLogID': 'c76960b1-aa24-454f-9fe7-f4f3960fefd4'
>   }]"
>   )

```
NSDictionary *dicResponse = (NSDictionary *)[data objectAtIndex:0];
```

gives me the same thing as last.

how to remove " as mikeweller suggest.

Comment: But that is store in the array as a string how can u get using "objectForkey"

Comment: Thanks Hamdullah shah, plz check updated code and comments for other answer,happy if you help me...!?!

Comment: check on the server side that JSON is created correctly because JSON use double quotes not single. http://json.parser.online.fr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the JSON parser to parse the string but as your string is generated with single quotes, JSON need to be with double quotes so first you have to change this on server side or at local side replace all single quote with double but that's not a good choice.

for parsing visit the following link

http://json.parser.online.fr

Comment: Thanks to mark my mind toward server side issue with quotes...!?!

Answer (score 3):

The error is telling you that `dicResponse` is actually a string.

This means the `SelectUserDataResult` key has a string value, which can be seen in the data you posted because `SelectUserDataResult`'s value is surrounded by double quotes.

Remove the surrounding `"` from `SelectUserDataResult` and your code should work.

If you are getting this string as JSON from an external source you'll have to decode it using [`NSJSONSerialization`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply, Please check part-2 updated in same question.

Comment: Your updated code still has everything wrapped up in a string.

Comment: Actually that string came from web service and that I've store in array as **[initWithObjects]**, how to remove it.

Comment: You'll have to parse it as JSON. Use `NSJSONSerialization`.

Comment: I already try NSJSONSerialization as it returns me null **NSString *jsonString = [data objectAtIndex:0];
    NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *jsonDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];**